# ADB Process kill error. Android 11

Tags: adb, android-11, processes

My camera doesn't work on a custom ROM (Android 11), I searched for a fix online, and it says that I have to restart the camera service, they said to run this command on ADB:

```
kill -HUP ps -A | grep camera | awk '{print $2}'
```

but when I hit enter it gave me an error of:

```
/system/bin/sh: kill: ps: arguments must be jobs or process IDs   
/system/bin/sh: kill: -A: arguments must be jobs or process IDs
```

---

I ran

```
ps -A | grep camera
```

It outputs

```
cameraserver    375    1   25432   2584 binder_thread_read a9825cec S android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-service 
camera          426    1   73104   2432 poll_schedule_timeout aea69eac S mm-qcamera-daemon
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Execute the command-parts separately, e.g. `ps -A | grep camera` if you can find the camera process at all. Edit your question and add the output of this command.

Comment: @Robert ,  i've added the output of he command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can only guess of syntax error. Go back where you found that command I am pretty sure you missed something, like `kill -HUP \`ps -A | grep camera | awk '{print $2}'\`` (note the difference between `\`` and `'`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmd nested in backticks processed from sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599682/cmd-nested-in-backticks-processed-from-sudo)